# Why does "send-mailmessage" work in Powershell Console but not in PowerShell ISE?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, powershell-ise

I am trying to send an email from PowerShell ISE.

The script I use is as simple as they get:

```
Send-mailmessage -from "me@company.com" -to "me@company.com" -subject "test" -smtpserver "smtp_server"
```

It fails with an error message:

> Send-mailmessage : Unable to connect to remote server

There are many reasons this could happen, answered in a lot of questions here. What puzzles me is that if I copy and paste the **exact same script** into a Powershell console, it works fine, and I get the mail.

**What could cause this difference of behavior between Powershell ISE and Powershell Console?**

I have tried to use the console `powershell -command "mycommand"`. It sends the mail.

I have tried using the x86 versions of both with the same results, it works with the console, not with the ISE.

Comment: Are you behind a corporate proxy?

Comment: Everything is done within the corporate network (sender, email server, exchange)

Comment: does that smtp server allow you to connect to it without authorization? Error is quite simple, your smtp server does not allow you to connect to it. Perhaps credentials, port, ssl, encoding... [Documentation on switches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-7)

Comment: Do you have antivirus running on your machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to disable the antivirus and run the code in ISE again? It might be possible that antivirus is blocking the outbound email.

[refer this issue on MS Technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3ee94356-f0d4-42e3-be55-8e963198b0f4/sendmailmessage-not-working-in-ise?forum=winserverpowershell) discussing similar issue.